# Python countdown function with input parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter

I have the following code to show a countdown in a given label in my GUI.

The code looks like this:

```
def countdown(self, a, remaining = None):
    if remaining is not None:
        self.remaining = remaining

    if self.remaining <= 0:
        a.configure(text="time's up!")
    else:
        a.configure(text="%d" % self.remaining)
        self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
        self.after(1000, self.countdown)
```

"a" is at the moment a placeholder variable for my label I will input in this function. My problem is that I don't know how to remain "a" while reusing my function with:

```
self.after(1000, self.countdown)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per tkinter doc, signature of after is:

```
after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args)
```

So you can pass "a" or "remaining" as arguments and collect it in the positional argument container *args and use them inside your function. By this way, your function remains generic.

Comment: Got it ! Thank you very much.